# JasperReports Server: drawText doesn't work in Linux System

Tags: linux, jboss, jasper-reports, barcode, jasperserver

I have recently used Barbecue barcode in a report with drawText property checked. 
It came up fine in my local server - *JBoss 5* + *Windows*. 
But, when I invoked the same report in *JBoss 5* + *Linux*, the Barcode is proper by the text is missing (draw Text). 
I am really finding it pretty hard to find out what the issue is.
Do you have come across similar kind of issue.

Comment: Can you compare the output between Windows and Linux when exporting to PDF?

Comment: @Israel, I did not get that. All I get the pdf file out of it and the text beneath the barcode is missing in Linux systems.